# Does Synapse have the ability to work with semi-structured data?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I have web app logs in my data lake. Some log entries have fields that others do not have. Can I work with this data in Synapse directly or do I have to normalize it with ADF first to match the schema in Synapse?

Answer (score 1):

One Azure Synapse feature you should really look at is [serverless SQL pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview),
(previously known as SQL on-demand) currently in preview.  It can deal with JSON, parquet and csv files in your data lake.

Do you have different web logs differentiated by their filename in the same place in your data lake, or different records within individual files?  If it's the former, you could simply write a SQL on-demand T-SQL statement and filter on the filename using the `filename` function, something like:

```
SELECT
    r.filename() AS [filename],
    *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'csv/taxi/yellow_tripdata_2017-*.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'SqlOnDemandDemo',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIRSTROW = 2) 
        WITH (C1 varchar(200) ) AS [r]
WHERE
    r.filename() IN ('yellow_tripdata_2017-10.csv', 'yellow_tripdata_2017-11.csv', 'yellow_tripdata_2017-12.csv');
```

Sample query adapted from Microsoft article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files#filename).  You can see you do not have to know the schema in advance.

there would be something that differentiated them, eg number of commas, some kind of identifier at the front of the record etc, please post more detail and sample data if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no (assuming it's not json logs). You can not use Azure Synapse's T-SQL to load such data. You must transform it before.

---

Azure Synapse is not only a DB. It's an umbrella under which services related to Analytics are offered. SQL Pool (Synapse DB) is one of them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/overview-what-is

It also offers orchestration features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-pipelines

It's a problem of plenty for you.

- Use JSON data type if you can. Support for it is in preview, I doubt that it'll scale (when querying the logs after you load them). But an option in theory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest
- As you already pointed out: Use something like ADF (Azure Data Factory) to transform the logs and load into Synapse DB.
- Use Spark built-into Synapse instead of ADF to do the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark
- Use Azure Functions written in Python using Pandas, with http-trigger-binding to datalake to do transform (to csv, orc, parquet). Then use COPY command to load into Synapse.

ADF could turn out to be expensive if it's not a one time thing.